# Unable to create wildcard (*) Cert with Kubernetes and Letsencrypt using Azure DNS zone

Tags: azure, nginx, kubernetes, dns, lets-encrypt

I'm quite new to Kubernetes. But so far was able to configure an AKS (Azure Kubernetes Services) cluster. I have multiple namespaces for my services (Dev, stage, prod). And configured an Ingress service using nginx (**into it's own namespace 'ingress-nginx'**). The setup works perfectly with HTTP.

My problems started when I tried to use HTTPS. First installed cert-manager by using [**this**](https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/kubernetes/) script. It has **created it own namespace again: 'cert-manager'** **I was not using HELM just regular manifest**. Also followed MS Azure [**DNS config**](https://cert-manager.io/docs/configuration/acme/dns01/azuredns/).

Everything seems correct I have my services, secrets, clusterIssuer, etc. Even challenge created in Azure DNS Zone. You can see it on Azure portal. But I did not get any certificate.

[image]

ClusterIssuer config:

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: 8b3s-org-letsencrypt
spec:
  acme:
    #server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: <...@gmail.com>
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: 8b3s-org-letsencrypt-key
    solvers:
    - selector:
      dns01:
        azuredns:
          clientID: ....
          clientSecretSecretRef:
          # The following is the secret we created in Kubernetes. Issuer will use this to present challenge to Azure DNS.
            name: azuredns-config
            key: client-secret
          subscriptionID: ....
          tenantID: "...."
          resourceGroupName: Web
          hostedZoneName: 8b3s.org
          # Azure Cloud Environment, default to AzurePublicCloud
          environment: AzurePublicCloud
```

Ingress config:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: 8b3s-virtual-host-ingress
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "8b3s-org-letsencrypt"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
     - '*.8b3s.org'
    secretName: 8b3s-org-letsencrypt-tls
  rules:
  - host: dev.8b3s.org
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: the8b3swebsite-development-ext
          servicePort: 8080
```

So the issue is every config seems OK but there is no Cert at all. **I got only an 'Opaque' ' tls.key:
1679 bytes' as '8b3s-org-letsencrypt-key' in the 'cert-manager' namespace.**

[image]

The **Cert got created for the 'ingress-nginx' namespaces '8b3s-org-letsencrypt-tls' as type 'kubernetes.io/tls'. But 'ca.crt: 0 bytes' and 'tls.crt: 0 bytes'**.

[image]

I was also looking into cert-manager pods output. Found those 2 logs weird (if needed I have the full logs):

```
I0222 22:51:00.067791       1 acme.go:201] cert-manager/controller/certificaterequests-issuer-acme/sign "msg"="acme Order resource is not in a ready state, waiting..." "related_resource_kind"="Order" "related_resource_name"="8b3s-org-letsencrypt-tls-1807766204-3808299645" "related_resource_namespace"="ingress-nginx" "resource_kind"="CertificateRequest" "resource_name"="8b3s-org-letsencrypt-tls-1807766204" "resource_namespace"="ingress-nginx" 

I0222 22:51:00.068069       1 sync.go:129] cert-manager/controller/orders "msg"="Creating additional Challenge resources to complete Order" "resource_kind"="Order" "resource_name"="8b3s-org-letsencrypt-tls-1807766204-3808299645" "resource_namespace"="ingress-nginx" 

E0222 22:51:01.876182       1 sync.go:184] cert-manager/controller/challenges "msg"="propagation check failed" "error"="DNS record for \"8b3s.org\" not yet propagated" "dnsName"="8b3s.org" "resource_kind"="Challenge" "resource_name"="8b3s-org-letsencrypt-tls-1807766204-3808299645-481622463" "resource_namespace"="ingress-nginx" "type"="dns-01"
```

Any idea what can be the problem?

**UPDATE:**
Added Azure NS records to my domain DNS as suggested. Waited an hour or so but there is no effect... Deleted existing CA secrets, restarted all Nginx, cert-manager Pods. And noticed the following error:

```
E0225 10:14:03.671099       1 util.go:71] cert-manager/controller/certificaterequests/handleOwnedResource "msg"="error getting order referenced by resource" "error"="certificaterequest.cert-manager.io \"8b3s-org-letsencrypt-tls-1807766204\" not found" "related_resource_kind"="CertificateRequest" "related_resource_name"="8b3s-org-letsencrypt-tls-1807766204" "related_resource_namespace"="ingress-nginx" "resource_kind"="Order" "resource_name"="8b3s-org-letsencrypt-tls-1807766204-3808299645" "resource_namespace"="ingress-nginx" 
E0225 10:14:03.674679       1 util.go:71] cert-manager/controller/certificates/handleOwnedResource "msg"="error getting order referenced by resource" "error"="certificate.cert-manager.io \"8b3s-org-letsencrypt-tls\" not found" "related_resource_kind"="Certificate" "related_resource_name"="8b3s-org-letsencrypt-tls" "related_resource_namespace"="ingress-nginx" "resource_kind"="CertificateRequest" "resource_name"="8b3s-org-letsencrypt-tls-1807766204" "resource_namespace"="ingress-nginx"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [whois record](https://whois.domaintools.com/8b3s.org) for your domain shows that it is still pointed at `NS57.DOMAINCONTROL.COM` and not the 4 Azure DNS resolvers you show in your screenshot. Thus, Let's Encrypt has no way of knowing they should use Azure to look up that `_acme-challenge` record, and it fails.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I'm blocked on this for a while...Ok so it means AKS config is correct but I have to modify my domain DNS? But exactly what? Sorry I'm not a network expert just a developer. Currently looking at my domain DNS records on Godaddy. What you were mentioning NS57.DOMAINCONTROL.COM cannot be changed. Added new NS records pointing to Azure like 30 mins ago. So far no affect.

Comment: As the close votes indicate, this is a site for programming questions, not for "how does DNS work." You may have better luck over on serverfault.com or by doing a little reading, because the problem you are trying to solve is not a new one.

Comment: I have to point out I just started work with Kubernetes and Docker in general a week ago. And configuring every component is at least overwhelming... Or may I say crazy :) So the original question was relevant I think. Good to know I got everything right at the first time. :) You were also right. Now I changed NS at Godaddy. Or say tried to change it but their site actually crashed with JS errors... So I had to contact support and ask a guy to update it. This whole story is madness. After waiting for propagation and deleting old keys + Pod "recycle" it works! Thanks you saved me a few days :)